# Pass int Into Function, the int into Switch, and change value of int

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement, return-value

```
int upgradeControl(int currentUpgrade) {

    // This section returns the value of an upgrade
    switch (currentUpgrade) {
        case 0: currentUpgrade = 0;
            break;
        case 1: currentUpgrade = 100;
            break;
        case 2: currentUpgrade = 300;
            break;
        case 3: currentUpgrade = 600;
            break;
        case 4: currentUpgrade = 1000;
            break;
        case 5: currentUpgrade = 1500;
            break;
        default: std::cout << "We have an error";
    }
}
```

I need my code to return a new value back to another function, but CLion says everything nested inside my switch is unreachable.

Comment: Use a reference parameter: `int upgradeControl(int& currentUpgrade) {` and have a `return` statement.

Comment: @Robert Bishop The function has no return statement. So the function returns nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Because the function begins with the type int, you must return an int. Also, based on this code it looks like you may want to pass currentUpgrade by reference. In such a case you could also make the function void.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks! Can not believe I missed that! The code is now up and running.

Answer (score 0):

```
int upgradeControl(int currentUpgrade) {
    // This section returns the value of an upgrade

    switch (currentUpgrade) {
        case 0: currentUpgrade = 0;
            break;
        case 1: currentUpgrade = 100;
            break;
        case 2: currentUpgrade = 300;
            break;
        case 3: currentUpgrade = 600;
            break;
        case 4: currentUpgrade = 1000;
            break;
        case 5: currentUpgrade = 1500;
            break;
        default: std::cout << "We have an error";
    }

    return currentUpgrade;
}
```